# Interview with the President Jobs or Interview with President Jobs?

Tags: grammar

Which is correct ? Or at least sounds better ?

For the CEO or President of a company.

Comment: Normally it would be "interview with Steve Jobs, president of XYZ Corp."  Except in this case it would require some time travel.

Answer (score 1):

From the example you gave, "Interview with President Jobs" is correct usage, and "Interview with the President Jobs" is not correct.

When combining a person's title with their name the word "the" is not used, just like if you were only referring to a person by their name.

It isn't very common to use the "title plus last name" form of address when referring to company presidents though. That form is used mainly for presidents of nation-states.

For company presidents, it is more common to include the company name as well as the person's name. For example, "Yahoo President Marissa Mayer".

Correct:

- President Washington
- His Excellency the President
- His Excellency President Washington
- Queen Elizabeth
- Her Majesty the Queen
- Her Majesty Queen Elizabeth

Incorrect:

- The President Washington
- His Excellency President
- His Excellency the President Washington
- The Queen Elizabeth
- Her Majesty Queen
- Her Majesty the Queen Elizabeth

The word "the" is used when we are referring to a person by their title alone, without using their name.

Watch out for extra words and punctuation that change the meaning of what is being said though.

This is also correct:

The new Queen, Elizabeth.

Here we are describing Elizabeth as "The new Queen". The word queen is now being used as part of an adjective phrase, instead of being part of the proper noun phrase "Queen Elizabeth".